# Is it possible to fire touch events when page load(In onload function)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

I am not getting how to call touch events when page load.
I have tried with below code but event is not firing. Can anybody tell me where am I doing wrong?

```
$(window).onload = setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('resetBtn').style.display = 'none';
    $('#splash').attr('src', 'img/splash.png');
    disableZoomButtons();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#splashDiv").remove();
        $('#menuBg').attr('src', 'img/wood.png');
        $('#about').attr('src', 'img/about1.png');
        $('#help').attr('src', 'img/help1.png');
        $('#newGame').attr('src', 'img/newgame.png');

        $('#newGame').on('touchstart', function (e) {
            alert("Start");
            enableZoomButtons();
            can = document.getElementById('can');
            cxt = can.getContext('2d');
            init();
        });
    });
}, 2000);
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<body>

<img id="background" />
<div id="splashDiv">
    <img id="splash" src="img/splash.png"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; position: absolute;" />
</div>
<div id="menuBgDiv">
    <img id="menuBg" src="img/wood.png"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1; position: fixed;" />
<ul>
    <li><img class="menus" id="newGame" src="img/newgame.png" />
    </li>
    <li><img class="menus" id="help" src="img/help1.png" />
    </li>
    <li><img class="menus" id="about" src="img/about1.png" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to call touch events in onload function(NOT triggers)

newGame id is image id defined in HTML. I need to click on the newGame image button then init() method has to call.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you asking for code that allows you to run the code once at page load, then every time the `touchstart` event is called?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Sir, in one word I need to call touch events when page load. Is it possible? Bcoz I am trying it but its not firing.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand. Are you asking how to run the function passed to `touchstart` on page load?

Comment: You want to fire the event or bind to the event?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes sir, actually that touchstart event is not firing in onload function.

Comment: What does firing mean to you? You don't have any code that fires an event, only code that binds to the event. Is the real event not firing? If that's the problem, stop saying onload.

Comment: @Anthony Sir, simple once I click the newGame image, init() has to call in the onload function. Its not working in onload. Touch start events are working fine in rest of the code

Comment: So it's not firing when the actual touchstart event occurs. You bind it within the onload event. Have you tried removing the settimeout?

Comment: @Anthony No sir its not firing and I have tried without settimeout method then also Not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to trigger event:

```
$('#newGame').on('touchstart', function (e) {
    alert("Start");
    enableZoomButtons();
    can = document.getElementById('can');
    cxt = can.getContext('2d');
    init();
})
.trigger("touchstart");
```

Comment: No sir, actually what I am trying is: displaying splash screen 2seconds after 2sec one more image will display menuBg in that there are three images newgame, about and help. When I click the newgame image then only init(0 method has to call IF I trigger it, page load only init() execute.

Comment: @Mallikarjun: you should have wrote that in your question - it's a good idea to be as detailed as possible in the first place to prevent this sort of confusion.

Comment: Yes I will mention in question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(window).onload
```

use

```
$(document).ready( function() {} );
```

possible problem is that you are attaching the event even before loading the actual element. And also what is the use of the setTimeout? i don't quite get it. Just use the code above and remove the setTimeout.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    document.getElementById('resetBtn').style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#splash').attr('src', 'img/splash.png');
        $("#splashDiv").remove();
        $('#menuBg').attr('src', 'img/wood.png');
        $('#about').attr('src', 'img/about1.png');
        $('#help').attr('src', 'img/help1.png');
        $('#newGame').attr('src', 'img/newgame.png');
        $('#newGame').click( function (e) {
            alert("Start");
            can = document.getElementById('can');
            cxt = can.getContext('2d');
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Edited:** I removed the unnecessary functions but you can put them again

Comment: $('#newGame').touchstart( function (e) {/*function*/} );

Comment: can you give more detail? i don't quite get what you are trying to achieve though

Comment: Just a note: there's no need for the `>` and the `<pre>` tags in Markdown for your code - I've edited it.

Comment: Settimeout is for displaying the splash screen for 2second, once time get over I have to click newgame image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V85k4/6/ --> check this out, if this is what you want to achieve. I removed unnecessary codes(non existing functions, but you can put them again)

Comment: i tested it on iPad running on ios7 works fine for me. Just notify me for any news

Comment: @YjaeDalina Yes sir, exactly I need this only BUT its not working in Android devices:-( Same code I pasted in onload function BUT its not working(newGame touch is not occurring), please help me sir

Comment: @YjaeDalina Yes sir, its working fine now. Actually HTML code wa wrong. Thanks a lot. Can you post the answer here then I can accept it, may help to others.